# On page reload, "window.print()" does not load the print dialog in Google Chrome 77.0.3865.120. This happens when an IFRAME is used with a PDF as SRC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, iframe

## Problem Description

With JavaScript, you can programmatically trigger the print dialog, by using `window.print()`. However, as soon as an `iframe` is loaded into the page with a **PDF** as the `src` and you refresh the page, the print dialog will no longer be shown when clicking on the button that should execute the `window.print()` function.

The issue does not happen in MS Edge, neither in Firefox... Only the latest version of **Google Chrome (77.0.3865.120)** seems to be affected. Is this a Chrome bug?

## Steps to reproduce the bug

1. Drop the below code in an html file and put it on a webserver (e.g. WampServer)
2. Navigate in Chrome to index.html
3. Click [Open print dialog]          ==> Ok
4. Click [Create iframe]              ==> Ok
5. Refresh index.html
6. Click [Open print dialog]          ==> Not ok! Will not open the print dialog
7. Only solution is closing the current Chrome Tab and reopening index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Chrome bug with window.print()</title>
        <script>
            function createMyIframe() {

                // Create new element    
                var myIframe = document.createElement('iframe');

                // Add src attribute
                myIframe.src = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf';

                // Suggestion of Amy does not solve the issue:
                // Adding a **sandbox** attribute with a space-separated list of pre-defined values that will REMOVE the particular restrictions.
                // Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp
                // Adding the following line is no solution. The iframe that is used in this example, will simply no longer open. Both the <head> and <body> tags of the iframe will be empty.
                // myIframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox   allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation';

                // Add the iframe to the page
                document.body.appendChild(myIframe);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Chrome version 77.0.3865.120 (Official build) (64-bits)</h1>
        <h2>Bug with JavaScript "window.print()"</h2>

        <hr>

        <button onclick="window.print();">Open print dialog</button>
        <button onclick="createMyIframe()">Create Iframe</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Conclusion

The `window.print()` dialog becomes useless, as soon as you have an `iframe` on your page with a PDF as the `src` attribute.

Comment: Possibly related to https://github.com/NWebsec/NWebsec/issues/77 and https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/block-modal-dialogs-sandboxed-iframe/

Comment: I provided an extra line to add the sandbox attribute to the iframe, and included all possible attribute values to remove the particular restrictions. At first sight, this will solve the issue as the print popup will now open. However, the iframe itself is no longer loaded into the page.

Comment: Even with the latest update on the Chrome Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit) issue still exist.

Comment: The issue has been officially confirmed by the Chromium Bugs team. See this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013635#c17).

Answer (score 1):

[According to the Chromium team](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1013635#c31), this bug will be fixed in Chrome 80 (due [to be released Feb 2, 2020](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule)).

A temporary fix for users can be to disable the MimeHandlerView in cross-process frame: **chrome://flags/#mime-handler-view-in-cross-process-frame**

Or, as the asker said, re-open the tab/window.

For developers, I sadly haven't found a good way to fix this until then. `window.onbeforeprint(event)` is not called, and `window.print()` returns `undefined` regardless.

Comment: Can confirm that the temporary fix does work, however, this bug appears to persist even into version 80, as I am still experiencing it. Version 80.0.3987.132. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @CalIrvine I confirmed the Chrome 80 release fixed the issue for the company I worked for, so perhaps you guys are experiencing are subtlety we weren't. Our problem was essentially exactly as described by the OP.

Comment: Interesting. I've only tried it on my machine, so maybe something specific to my install of Chrome is messing it up. My issue is also basically identical to the one described above. I'll keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: @AskeB I have also tried it after updating it to Chrome 80, but issue is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

No problem in recent 101.0.4951.67 (Official Build)

[image]
[image]

***However you should not expect a PDF media handler to work the same way in all browsers it is the client decides the PDF handling methods.***

[image]
[image]
[image]